# Beats token request yields invalid_client error

Tags: beatsmusic

Per https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs/read/getting_started/Web_Server_Applications, I'm successfully getting the authorization code. I'm then performing the below curl post request and I'm receiving a "invalid_client" error in response. Note that `MY_KEY`, `MY_SECRET`, `MY_REDIRECT_URI` and `AUTHORIZATION_CODE` are correct.

```php
$postUrl = 'https://partner.api.beatsmusic.com/v1/oauth2/token';

$postData = array(
    'client_id' => MY_KEY, 
    'client_secret' => MY_SECRET, 
    'redirect_uri' => MY_REDIRECT_URI, 
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code', 
    'code' => AUTHORIZATION_CODE
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Any clue why I'm getting the error? I'm expecting to get a json response with the access and refresh tokens. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should sent the data with Content-Type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the above code may produce `multipart/form-data` which did not work for me at least some weeks ago.